# Limit fields_for to only 1 New Record

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form that i want to add comments to a company. but i only want the New form fields to show not the previous one to edit..

I just want the New Empty field... not all the previous comments...

Controller:

```
  def show
    @company_profile = CompanyProfile.find(params[:id])
    1.times do
      @company_profile.company_notes.build
      @company_profile.dispatchers.build
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @company_profile }
    end
  end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for @company_profile, :html => { :class => 'sky-form boxed comments' } do |f| %>
    <fieldset>
      <%= f.fields_for :company_notes do |builder| %>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-md-12">
              <section>
                <label class="input">
                  <%= builder.text_field :notes, :placeholder => "Comment" %>
                  <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Enter Comments</b>
                </label>
              </section>
            </div>
          </div>
      <% end %>
    </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

I just want the new empty field not the 2 others

[image]

Exact code that fixed for me so you dont have extra rows or divs

```
<%= form_for @company_profile, :html => { :class => 'sky-form boxed comments' } do |f| %>
    <fieldset>
      <%= f.fields_for :company_notes do |builder| %>
          <% if builder.object.new_record? %>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-md-12">
              <section>
                <label class="input">
                      <%= builder.text_field :notes, :placeholder => "Comment" %>
                  <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Enter Comments</b>
                </label>
              </section>
            </div>
          </div>
          <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What happens when you give `<% if builder.object.new_record? %><%= builder.text_field :notes, :placeholder => "Comment" %><% end %>`

Comment: I will be adding it as an answer then :)

Comment: I had to extend it to just inside of the fields for so that extra diva was created... will post exact code

Comment: Oh. Great! Post it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code would work for you

```
<% if builder.object.new_record? %>
  <%= builder.text_field :notes, :placeholder => "Comment" %>
<% end %>
```